# How to add git hash to Vue.js Component

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, vue.js, vue-component

I want to create a vue.js component which will display the package.json version number and hash of most recent git commit. Here is the code so far:

```
<template>
  <div class="versionLabel">Version: {{version}} (HASH)</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { version } from '../../package.json';

@Component
export default class VersionLabel extends Vue {
  get version() {
    return version;
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
div {
  background-color: rgb(60, 172, 60);
  color: lightgray;
}
</style>
```

I am deploying to Heroku using the commands

```
"postinstall": "if test \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"production\" ; then npm run build ; fi ",
"start": "node server.js",
```

in package.json and this simple server:

```
const express = require('express');
const serveStatic = require("serve-static")

app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/dist'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

The version number is working (Although suggestions for improvement are welcome) but how can I add the git hash in place of HASH?

Comment: Duplicates (?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518389/get-hash-of-most-recent-git-commit-in-node

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. That is helpful but that would need to be run on the node server. How would I pass the result to the vue component?

Comment: What are you using to build the Vue.js application? Is it a `vue-cli` project?

Comment: Yes it is. The command is: `vue-cli-service build`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Install [git-describe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-describe) as a dev dependency (e.g. `yarn add --dev git-describe`).

In `vue.config.js` add:

```
const {gitDescribe, gitDescribeSync} = require('git-describe');
process.env.VUE_APP_GIT_HASH = gitDescribeSync().hash
```

Now, in every component, we have `process.env.VUE_APP_GIT_HASH` variable.

Here is how I added it to my app: https://github.com/Quantum-Game/quantum-game-2/pull/164 (with some discussion).

### Other approaches

There are other approaches, e.g. using [git-revision-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-revision-webpack-plugin) (example for [the Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/trying-to-add-gitrevisionplugin-to-cli-3/65567)):

```
const GitRevisionPlugin = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  'chainWebpack': config => {
    config.plugin('define').tap(args => {
      const gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin()
      args[0]['process.env']['VUE_APP_COMMIT_HASH'] = JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash())
      return args
    })
  }
}
```

Another way is to use git directly, with [child-process](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/child_process/).

### See also

- [Including git commit hash and date in webpack build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400314/including-git-commit-hash-and-date-in-webpack-build)
- [Get hash of most recent git commit in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518389/get-hash-of-most-recent-git-commit-in-node)
- [Git log output to XML, JSON, or YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600445/git-log-output-to-xml-json-or-yaml)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not familiar with Heroku, however I hope some parts of my solution you'll find useful.

I'm developing a vue application, I use GitLab CI/CD and it's deployed to an S3 bucket on AWS then distributed with cloudfront. Sometimes our client will ask for changes that have already been made. So to prevent confusion I wanted to include a the git hash in the footer of the app so we can quickly check that they are looking at the most up-to-date version of the app.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I included the following bash commands:

```
hash=`git describe --always`
echo "\"$hash\"" > src/assets/hash.json
```

This creates a `hash.json` file, and the only contents of this file are the most recent commit hash as a string. e.g. `"015d8f1"`

I assume when you deploy to Heroku there is a similar way to execute bash commands.

From there you can just read in that file in any component and use it as data. e.g.

```
<script>
import GitHash from "@/assets/hash.json";

export default {
  name: "TheFooter",
  data() {
    return {
      GitHash: GitHash
    };
  }
};
</script>
```