# Add hash of most recent git commit to footer of pdf via markdown-pdf

Tags: node.js, git, pdf, gulp, markdown

I am using [markdown-pdf](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf) via gulp to convert .md files to .pdf. I want to get the sha of the latest git commit and add it to the footer. I can get the hash like so in my gulpfile.js ([found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518389/get-hash-of-most-recent-git-commit-in-node)):

```
revision = require('child_process')
  .execSync('git rev-parse HEAD')
  .toString().trim();
```

But how can I get that into my footer?

Below is my code for markdown-pdf that I am using in my gulpfile.js:

```
function docsToPdf() {
    return src(["Views/Documentation/Files/*.md", "!Views/Documentation/Files/_README.md"])
        .pipe(markdownPdf({
            preProcessMd: preProcessMd,
            remarkable: {
                html: true
            },
            paperBorder: "1cm",
            runningsPath: "Content/Pdf/assets/js/runnings.js",
            cssPath: "Content/Pdf/assets/css/pdf.min.css"
        }))
        .pipe(dest("Content/Pdf"))
}
```

And my runnings.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    header: {
        height: '2cm',
        contents: function (pageNum) {
            if (pageNum == 1) {
                return '<header class="pdf-header" style="padding-bottom: 20px;"><h2 style="text-align:center;margin:0;">Documentation</h2></header>'
            }
            return ''
        }
    },

    footer: {
        height: '1.5cm',
        contents: function (pageNum, numPages) {
            return '<footer class="pdf-footer" style="padding-top:20px;"><p style="float:left;width:33.33%;margin:0;font-size:10px;">' + new Date().toDateString() + '</p><p style="float:left;width:33.33%;margin:0;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">&copy; 2020</p><p style="float:right;width:33.33%;margin:0;font-size:10px;text-align:right;">Page ' + pageNum + ' of ' + numPages + '</p></footer>'
        }
    }
}
```

And my preProccessMd:

```
function preProcessMd() {
    var splitter = split()
    var docsUrl = "https://example.org/docs/";
    var urlOne = /\[\[((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)\|(.*?)]]/g;
    var urlImg = /(\()(images)/g;
    var replacer = through(function (data, path) {
        this.queue(
            data
                .replace(urlOne, (_, x, y) => `[${x}](${docsUrl}${y.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, '-$&').toLowerCase()})`)
                .replace(urlImg, "$1$2".replace("$2", "content/images/docs"))
            + "\n"
        )
    })

    splitter.pipe(replacer)
    return duplexer(splitter, replacer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use the `preProcessMd` method to inject the SHA into the footer. You do seem to have the preprocessor defined in `preProcessMd: preProcessMd,`. Is that actually doing anything? If so, what is the definition?

EDIT, after update from OP: Quick and dirty solution would be to use an empty `span` where you want the SHA to go. Then look for that span and replace with the SHA in your `preProcessMd`. For e.g., `<span class="git-hash"></span>`. Then replace `<span class="git-hash">` with `<span>YOUR-SHA`.

You might need to update your gulp task like so:

```
function docsToPdf() {
    revision = require('child_process')
      .execSync('git rev-parse HEAD')
      .toString().trim();

    return src(["Views/Documentation/Files/*.md", "!Views/Documentation/Files/_README.md"])
        .pipe(markdownPdf({
            preProcessMd: preProcessMd.bind(this, revision),
            remarkable: {
                html: true
            },
            paperBorder: "1cm",
            runningsPath: "Content/Pdf/assets/js/runnings.js",
            cssPath: "Content/Pdf/assets/css/pdf.min.css"
        }))
        .pipe(dest("Content/Pdf"))
}
```

And your `function preProcessMd() {` to `function preProcessMd(revision) {`

NOTE: I'm unsure if the `preProcessMd.bind(this, ...` is going to be problematic or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my post to include that function. It mostly is just replaces some urls right now.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not work. I'm thinking that maybe the `preProcessMd` is ran before the footer is injected by runnings.js, so it has nothing to find/replace.

Comment: @Designxsteph hmmm that's weird. So it goes MD -> HTML -> PDF. Only thing I can think of is to do the replacement in `preProcessHtml`. Could you give that shot?